# Image Not Showing up in if statement

Tags: php, mysql

This should be simple. Trying to echo an image if it exists in a directory. Else guest.png should echo. So far, the guest.png is echoing fine. My problem is that I can never the .jpg image when it does exist. I have double-checked the source. The image just shows up as an empty image box.

```
 <?php
  $ID=$row_RecordsetLast['ID'];

$image = '../../pics/'.$ID.'.jpg';




if (file_exists($image)) {
    echo '<img src=$image alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
} else {
    echo '<img src="guest.png" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: What does var_dump($image) show?

Comment: `../../pics/` on backend and on frontend are 2 different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error, the following code worked for me. I guess variables did not work well within img source.

```
<?php
$ID=$row_RecordsetLast['ID'];

$image = '../../pics/'.$ID.'.jpg';


if (file_exists($image)) {
    echo '<img src="../../pics/' . $ID . '.jpg" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
} else {
    echo '<img src="guest.png" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not wraping the image address with apostrophes or quotes.

Change the line to this:

```
echo '<img src="$image" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
```

Should work, considering the given address will be reached by the HTML page.

Have in mind that `../../pics/` may not work depending on your project's folder structure.

Comment: "wraping the image address with apostrophes or quotes" is not needed

Comment: I do believe it is. HTML is really imperative about what value you set to it's tag's attributes. The src should be a string. PHP wouldn't echo those quotes by itself.

Comment: No my friend. It is not. Just try it out ;)

Comment: Actually, you should always wrap attributes in quotes. It might work without in many situations but that doesn't make it correct. If you don't wrap them in quotes, you will get messed up markup if a value gets a space in it. Better to always be consistent and use quotes.

Comment: Crap. [You are right](https://jsfiddle.net/nbd6gs8m/). It works. But I think you should wrap in quotes anyways, all the time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes agree

Comment: Tried with "$image" and using the direct hyperlink instead of ../../ of http://mydomain/pics. Still does not display.

Comment: I don't think using the direct hyperlink will validate on your if. You should use the dynamic address for the conditional and then the direct link for the img tag.

Comment: Still not working. Tried.                                                                                             <?php
   $ID=$row_RecordsetLast['ID'];
 
 $image = '../../pics/'.$ID.'.jpg';
 $path = "http://domain.com/pics/";
 $ext = ".jpg";
 $link = $path.$ID.$ext;
 
    if (file_exists($image)) {
        echo '<img src="$link" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="guest.png" alt="" width="110" height="161" />';
    }
?>